# ListFragment missing divider

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am modifying my existing app to use ListFragment instead of ListView.

I am not able to set divider using JAVA. No exceptions are thrown. ListFragment is displayed with no dividers.

```
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        lv = getListView();  
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        lv.setDividerHeight(1);

        lv.setDivider(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.black));

        lv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.merge)); //white background
        lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
        lv.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false);    

        setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());

      }
```

What am I doing wrong? You help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use lv.setDividerHeight(1) after lv.setDivider(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.black));

So Invert them:

```
lv.setDivider(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.black));
lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your divider can't just be a color because it also needs a width. You are Retrieving a drawable but actually are grabbing a color. You should create a line drawable and put it in your drawable folder that is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"  />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```